# dynamically referring to array position within current loop iteration

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

So I couldnt find anything on this so I figured maybe someone would point me in the correct direction for my predicament. Is this the correct way to reference previous array positions based off the current position during a loop iteration?

I dont really have something I am working on, I just want to know what the correct way to reference this without having to statically declare what position a(i) and (a-1)/(a-2) would be.

Can I use offset for this? Or is there another more simpler way of going about this?

Here is a sample of what I was curious about. I guess this exmaples checks for whether or not the past two iterations where equal and if not make the current equal to the current block start/end values

```
  For i = LBound(a) to UBound(a)
      If Something = This And (a(i)-2) <> (a(i)-1) Then (i) = BlockStart & " & " & BlockEnd
```

Comment: `...And a(i-2) <> a(i-1) Then...`  but you need to check that `i>=LBound(a)+2` before doing that.

Comment: Even if BlockStart & BlockEnd are set before the first loop iteration? I guess that would mean that the first two array positions would always need to be set outside of the loop. I guess I didn't think that the first two iterations would actually cause a "subscript out of range" error, but that totally makes sense.

Comment: Yes - you can't reference an array position which doesn't exist: that will always raise an error

Comment: Right. Since I havent been working on something specific and was just generally curious about correct syntax, that hadnt occured to me till you mentioned it :)

Comment: So I tried this in a simple loop and the i>=LBound(a)+2  and a(i-2) <> a(i-1) throws a subscript out of range error anyway. I may have to try and alter it so it doesn't check this at all until its on loop#3

Comment: In VBA, unlike some other languages, `If Test1 And Test2 Then` doesn't "short-circuit" (stop testing if Test1 is False) - *all* `And`-ed expressions will be evaluated, causing an error if `a(i-2)` involves an out-of-bounds array access.  You need to put your `i>=LBound(a)+2` by itself, before the next checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if something=this and I=2 then 
    if a(I-2)<>a(I-1) then
          a(I)="xyz"
    end if
end if
```

If I understand the *question*

I think this will happen though after it's happened once as a(0)=a a(1)=b so then a(2)="blck start" then when on 3 a(2) will differ to a(1) by this function....

Comment: Well I was certainly hoping to avoid declaring what state I is in, if that makes sense. Mainly I want to check a(i) against the two previous values. Though I do admit it seems a bit ambiguous sense the first two iterations will always fail to match. Edited to be more clear